# How to resize to fit and center image in a position absolute div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need an image to be resized to fit in inside a div. This div must, necessarely, no matter what, be an `position: absolute;` div. Apart from the image have 100% from its greatest dimension, it should be centered in the other way.

I could resize to fit it, but can't center. I tried to make it inline and use vertical-align, but it didn't work.

Since code worth more than words, check my [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hY7r6/1/).

This is the code from the jsfiddle:

CSS:

```
.relative {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;

    <!-- Next is not important, only to display better -->
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute">
        <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/pashok/pashok1101/pashok110100126/8578310-vertical-shot-of-cute-red-cat.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only for semi-new browsers:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Absolutely position all the things!

`transform` still needs browser prefixes I hear. `-webkit-` works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/G9Z7U/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I [created a fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Z7U/), but don't seems to work :(

Comment: You still need the max width etc. And the browser prefixes. I only typed what you should add. I added a fiddle link in the answer.

Comment: You don't need the --webkit thing. Without it, works on firefox, chrome, ie11, ie10, ie9, but I can't make it work in IE8. This was my last try:  [tested with this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fotanus/G9Z7U/13/). Not sure if you understand those filter stuff?

Comment: My Chrome still needs a `-webkit-` prefix. IE8 won't work and that's fine because everyone using IE8 deserves broken websites and horrible mulilation.

Comment: for most than I agree with your comment, [it stills almost 21% of the web](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), can't afford not supporting it in this project :(

Comment: And while we keep catering that 21%, it won't shrink. If you use IE8, you don't get pretty centered images. I don't think there's a ms filter for XY-translation, but I might be wrong, there are a lot of em.

Answer (score 2):

you may put the image to background instead of an img tag.

```
<div class="absolute">
    <img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Spacer.gif">
</div>

.absolute {
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

however, if you can set a fixed height for the div, you can use this:

```
.absolute { line-height:360px; }
.absolute img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I didn't managed it to work. Check out [this fiddle I created for it](http://jsfiddle.net/3cZbL/1/)

Comment: You still need the absolute stuff in `.absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/3cZbL/2/

Comment: Thanks! It works all down to ie9, but fails on IE8. The first cat is expanded. [take a look](http://i.imgur.com/ndYHP6i.png). Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: IE8 does not support background-size ... http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts in this way, you may use the 2nd method then, or get a plugin for IE8 background-size emulation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand the question…

```
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    line-height:350px; //new
}
img {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; // new
    vertical-align:middle; // new
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I [created a fiddle for you solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KLPd5/), to test it. What I need is having the same amount of red in both sides. Right now the images are stuck on the top or the left, so there is red in only one of the sides. It should work for any `div.absolute` sizes and any image sizes.